# BLE not reading properly?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm creating a scanning app for BLE sensors. I'm curious to know if its just me or if anyone is experiencing my problem.

I'm trying to scan roughly 1,000 ble sensors passing by my gateway. However I'm getting a good amount of missed reads. Is it just me or is anyone experiencing this, where not all BLE sensors are read? Could it just be purely a volume thing or something I haven't considered?

Thanks

Comment: I forgot to mention, the 1000 take around 2-5 minutes to pass by the gateway.

Comment: Please share your code. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example <https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve>. For more information, please see How to Ask<https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask> and take the tour<stackoverflow.com/tour>.

Answer (score 1):

This is purely a question of statistics. Your scanner has a certain scan interval during which it cycles through the three advertisement channels (37, 38, 39), and each sensor has an advertisement interval, during which it does the same. So there is always a probability that the scanner is currently on another channel than the advertisement being sent, in which case it will be missed.

What that probability is exactly depends on the interval settings of the scanner and the sensor, and also on how long each sensor will be within reception range.